# Android Wear Preview app - which smartphones are compatible?

Tags: wear-os

I got invitation to the Android Wear Developer program but when I try to install the Android Wear Preview app I see information that my device (Samsung Galaxy S2) is not compatible with the app. Is there some kind of list of devices compatible with Android Wear Preview app?

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a device spesific restriction, but according to [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/wear/preview/start.html#SetupApp)

```
Note: The Android Wear Preview app is compatible with Android 4.3 and higher and is not available for the Android emulator.
```

Edit: I think BLE is used for communication between smartphone and watch. So obviously that would be hardware restriction.

Comment: Ah, it makes sense, I have 4.2 installed. Thank you!

Comment: I have a nexus 7 device which I updated to 4.4.2 recently.Still then its showing "This app is incompatible".

Comment: [Loius Gray announced Already supported for Nexus 7 device](https://plus.google.com/communities/113381227473021565406) `Android Wear Preview App Updated for N7, Tablet Support`

Answer (score 3):

You need a 4.3+ Android smartphone. Because the Notification listener functionality has been added with API level 18.

Tablets were stated to be supported but right now they're filtered out from the store. You can still manually install the APK though.

Bluetooth LE isn't mandatory - for the preview at least.

Comment: tablets will be supported in the next few days: https://plus.google.com/100535338638690515335/posts/jWdYBAfZTyf