# Android Wear Preview app is incompatible with my device

Tags: android, google-play, wear-os

I try to download the Android Wear Preview app from Google Play Store, but it shows "This app is incompatible with your device." I use HTC 802W, android version is 4.4.2

I really don't know what is wrong, or Android Wear Preview app doesn't support HTC ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22526118/android-wear-preview-app-which-smartphones-are-compatible

Answer (score 1):

> Note: The Android Wear Preview app is compatible with Android 4.3 and higher and is not available for the Android emulator.

reference from [Android Wear Preview app - which smartphones are compatible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22526118/android-wear-preview-app-which-smartphones-are-compatible)

Or using Market Helper, [The Ultimate Guide to Installing Incompatible Android Apps from Google Play](http://www.howtogeek.com/138500/the-ultimate-guide-to-installing-incompatible-android-apps-from-google-play/)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, now I find the easy solution to me: Just download the preview app through Google play app on my phone. There is no incompatible issue.

This is pretty weird to me that I can't download on laptop but can download on my phone. Not sure if it's a common thing with Android, since I am new to Android. I only used iphone before, just recently started to try Android after got the glass﻿